# What does 'p' represent in a function's type?

Tags: haskell, function-definition

Given the following function definition:

```
f xs = []
```

its type is

```
f :: p -> [a]
```

From this, how should you interpret what `p` means?

Does it just mean *anything*? As in, `f` takes in *literally-any-value* and returns a list?

Comment: Yes, `f` takes a value of any type and returns an empty list.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the clarification, even if it was a dull question :)

Comment: `xs` is conventionally only used  for variables of a list type. Your `f` has the type you claim it has, but it took me some time to see that because of your choice of `xs` as its argument pattern.

Comment: This function was not thought of by me; and because of its use of `xs` (an intentional choice), I had to ask my question for clarification.

Comment: OK, so the `xs` is, like the `p`, a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `p` can be any type. Important to note that `a` is any type possibly other than `p`, as @bereal has mentioned in thr comments

Comment: Any type _possibly_ other than `p` :)

Comment: Why can't a = p?

Comment: _possibly_ different means: "it _can_ be different". It _doesn't_ mean " it cannot be equal". Modal logic is difficult....